# disappear the background image while change browser width

Tags: css, background

I have a sidebar with 2 background images. This is my CSS:

```
background-color: #fff;
background-image: url('img/back-1.png'), url('img/back-2.png');
background-position: left top, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
background-size: 100% auto, 100% auto;
```

when I change the width of the browser with the mouse (I use responsive design), the second image disappears in some position. But if I refresh the page or change the width, everything restores. Do you have any idea why does the image disappear?

Comment: you are making first image size 100%, and so it covers all the browser page..and the second image is pushed down. So it seems to disappears.

Comment: What browser did you test this in? Is there an online example of your problem? Maybe you could create a [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/).

Comment: Second @JasperDeVries: As it is this question is very hard to answer. Can you add some more details? Add some html and (links to) sample images so the question contains a short but working example. Explain what you mean by "*some* position". Add the example in a fiddle as well.

Comment: have the same issue with only one background image

Comment: My problem was solved, I put the background-image below the background size, need to put it above it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue,
I made 2 classes of CSS,
Detected the browser width by JavaScript,
Attached the right one to the class by JavaScript;